# Unknow shortcode read on display site

Tags: shortcode, captions

I put the caption on a picture like this, the blog looks good,

[image]

but in the compact view, I receive this problem

[image]

I guess the editor can not read the HTML tag, Is anyone know what happened?
[image]

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by compact view? Where are your screenshots from? What are they of?

Comment: That error from my company blog, it means I create a post and when I move to the website, I got an error like the second picture.

Comment: But how is it being displayed? Is that a widget? Where is the code that displays that content on the frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an HTML tag, it's a shortcode. If your theme used the `the_excerpt()` function for displaying the 'compact version' of the post content then this wouldn't appear. WordPress strips shortcodes out of post excerpts to prevent this happening.

If your theme is using its own method for generating the excerpt then its developer needs to fix the theme so that excerpts properly remove shortcodes. This can be achieved with the [`strip_shortcodes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/) function.

Comment: I fixed it simply by deleting the caption attribute of the picture. Also, I recommend this to our Wordpress Dev, thank for your help.